# Search Engine Site Map Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, .net-3.5, seo, sitemap

If possible can anyone tell me how can I implement a search engine sitemap with asp.net. My website has content that expires frequently and new stuff comes in, that's why I wanted it updated whenever the search engine crawler comes to my site.

I came across http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2005/12/02/432188.aspx which tells me that there was a library released by Microsoft year ago which could do exactly what I need. I cannot find it anywhere. Has it been made part of the ASP.Net 3.5 platform?

Are there any other better frameworks or libraries around which I can use for this same purpose?

Answer (score 0):

You should develop a dynamic site map. Most of the open blog platforms support that feature you can inspire from them.
You can develop for yourself. There is no need for external library.

This (http://www.stilx.com/sitemap.axd) is open blog ([BlogEngine.NET](http://www.dotnetblogengine.net/)).
Because It's open source you can look up the sitemap sources.